# android sms intent bundle where is the phone number?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, bundle, toast

this is part of my sms sent intent code

```
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
```

how do i make toast display "SMS sent - John Doe" instead of generic "SMS sent"?

i've looked at intent, bundle.setkey looking for the phone number; they have null values, am i looking at the wrong places?

thanks for helps and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SMS_SENT);
intent.putExtra("MobileNumber", SmsNumber);
```

and in onRecieve u can catch as follows

```
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                info += "Message Sent successfully !!";
                countEntered++;

                String tempMobileNumber = intent
                        .getStringExtra("MobileNumber");
```

Comment: ah ok, i thought the "destination address/phone number" in sendMultipartTextMessage would be available somewhere that i can get at.

Comment: you can get only through intent